# Use `dplyr` to divide rows by group

Tags: r, dplyr

On my attempt to learn `dplyr`, I want to divide each row by another row, representing the corresponding group's total.

I generated test data with

```
library(dplyr)

# building test data
data("OrchardSprays")

totals <- OrchardSprays %>% group_by(treatment) %>%
  summarise(decrease = sum(decrease))
totals$decrease <- totals$decrease + seq(10, 80, 10)
totals$rowpos = totals$colpos <- "total"

df <- rbind(OrchardSprays, totals)
```

Note the line `totals$decrease <- totals$decrease + seq(10, 80, 10)`: for the sake of the question, I assumed there was an additional `decrease` for each `treatment`, which was not observed in the single lines of the data frame but only in the "total" lines for each group.

What I now want to do is adding another column `decrease_share` to the data frame where each line's `decrease` value is divided by the corresponding `treatment` groups total `decrease value`.

So, for `head(df)` I would expect an output like this

```
> head(df)
  decrease rowpos colpos treatment treatment_decrease
1       57      1      1         D           0.178125
2       95      2      1         E          0.1711712
3        8      3      1         B         0.09876543
4       69      4      1         H         0.08603491
5       92      5      1         G          0.1488673
6       90      6      1         F          0.1470588
```

My real world example is a bit more complex (more group variables and also more levels), therefore I am looking for a suitable solution in `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a total `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr) #version >= 1.0.0
OrchardSprays %>% 
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  summarise(decrease = sum(decrease)) %>%
  mutate(decrease = decrease + seq(10, 80, 10),
         rowpos = "total",
         colpos = "total") %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate(OrchardSprays, across(rowpos:colpos, as.character))) %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  mutate(treatment_decrease = decrease / decrease[rowpos == "total"])
# A tibble: 72 x 5
# Groups:   treatment [8]
   treatment decrease rowpos colpos treatment_decrease
   <fct>        <dbl> <chr>  <chr>               <dbl>
 1 A               47 total  total               1    
 2 B               81 total  total               1    
 3 C              232 total  total               1    
 4 D              320 total  total               1    
 5 E              555 total  total               1    
 6 F              612 total  total               1    
 7 G              618 total  total               1    
 8 H              802 total  total               1    
 9 D               57 1      1                   0.178
10 E               95 2      1                   0.171
# … with 62 more rows
```

Comment: thank you for this! it seems to be working! However, it's a bit misleading, that you also generate the test data in your answer :) It would be a bit easier to understand (also for other people) if you remove this part from your answer!

Comment: also, while this solution is very good, I would have expected, that `decrease[rowpos == "total"]` could also be replaced by an (easier) `dplyr` statement. Is this possible?

Comment: This was an attempt to introduce you to additional functionality of `dplyr`. I'm not sure that I agree that it is "misleading". I am not aware of a tidyverse verb that would replace the functionality of `[` in this instance as `filter` works on data.frames and not vectors.